# Problems debugging with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently experiencing a lot of problems with Chrome Developer Tools.

I put a breakpoint at line **52** in the following code :

[image]

If I hover the mouse cursor over **client**, it says that it is an *object*, and if I hover over **getStore()** it also says that is a *function*.

However if I then step over, i get :

[image]

Why is chrome behaving so inconsistently??

Does it have something to do with transpiling, or the fact that it is a react project?

Comment: All we can do is guess without a [mcve]

Comment: Do you also get that error if you don't put a breakpoint?